# AMD graphics card not detected - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) alongside Windows 10 on my laptop. It picked up my Intel integrated graphics just fine, but my AMD graphics card does not appear at all in Additional Drivers. Although Ubuntu works fine without using my AMD card at all, I get pretty poor battery life. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Additional info:
My computer is a Toshiba L50-B025D with an AMD Radeon R7 M260 graphics card.

Comment: I same problem in 17.4, but there is no response from amd and ubantu as well

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04 AMD drivers are pre-installed, and since 16.04 we can use only open source Radeon driver, there is no point in showing it in driver manager.
Also my last impressions are that the driver manager is broken.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install muon
```

and then

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This will show you the drivers that you can install so then you can install the driver manually using:

```
sudo apt-get install driver-package-name
```

You can also type this:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
```

to see what video card is in use at the moment.